# What is this language feature called: [objectname]: { foo: 'Bar' },

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I just saw this language feature for the first time. This enables you to assign values directly to a variable with the name saved in `MarkerDest` (which is also `"MarkerDest"`). Up until now I would do this like: `markers[MarkerDest] = ...`

**So what do you call this JavaScript language feature?**

```
const { MarkerDest, MarkerUpcoming, MarkerNext } = {
  MarkerDest: 'MarkerDest',
  MarkerUpcoming: 'MarkerUpcoming',
  MarkerNext: 'MarkerNext',
};

const markers = {
  [MarkerDest]: { foo: 'Bar' },
 };
```

Comment: It is called `Destructuring assignment`. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal it is not, pay attention to OP question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called **Computed Property Names**.

Source:

- http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer (*Computed property names* section)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of new features here.

The first line is using **destructuring assignment** to declare the values out of an object (or this could be done out of an array). You can read more about it on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

The second part when it is using the variable as a property on the next objects is called **computed properties**, where a variable is used as the key within an object.

Comment: OP is asking about the second instruction, not the first one. The first one is actually destructuring assignment though.

Answer (score 0):

It is a new feature in ECMAScript 6 know as **[Computed Property Names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames)**. It allows you to dynamically create property names using an expression in brackets `([ ])` similar to [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Example:

#### ECMAScript 6 — syntactic sugar: reduced

```
let obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    [ "baz" + quux() ]: 42
}
```

#### ECMAScript 5 — syntactic sugar: traditional

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar"
};
obj[ "baz" + quux() ] = 42;
```

You can get to read more from [MDN Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [MDN Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to really get how both operate.